# Convert H:i:s hour style in other format

Tags: php, date

I would like to know how can I change

```
$var = "01:30:00";
```

to

```
$var = "1.5";
```

in PHP ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines...

```
<?php 
function timeToHours($time) {
    $hoursMinsSecs = explode(':', $time);
    return $hoursMinsSecs[0] + $hoursMinsSecs[1] / 60 + $hoursMinsSecs[2] / 3600;
}

$var = "01:30:00";

echo timeToHours($var);
?>
```